# How to loop through values of a combobox and not displayed items in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, loops, for-loop, combobox

I have a combobox that took its contect from this query from sql

```
sql = "select BookID,Title from 
Books ......"
    Dim da2 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    da2 = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da2.Fill(dt)
    con.Close()
    cb.DataSource = dt
    cb.DisplayMember = "Title"
```

so as you can see the combobox displayed member is "Title" column and not "ID"... 
Now if i want to loop through the ID column what would be the code ??

Comment: Why loop, you didnt mention that.... `For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows... If dr("ID").ToString = ? Then` that will give you a start

Comment: Make `Id` the `ValueMember`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping through a ComboBox is an unusual thing to do, usually you only care about the selected item.
But you can loop over each item. In your case the items are a `System.Data.DataRow` object because you have bound it to a `DataTable`. So you can cast to that, then access the BookID column.

I am not a VB developer so I may have the syntax wrong so consider this more like psuedo code. Also note that if `item("BookID")` is Nothing then you will get an error so I have left it up to you to make sure your data is not null. Finally, I have made an assumption that BookID is an integer, maybe it isn't.

```
For Each item As DataRow In cb.Items
    Dim bookid = Integer.Parse(item("BookID").ToString())
Next
```